# How to always show Navigation bar in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have some old code in an Objective C iOS app that uses a splitview.
The nav bar is being hidden in the detail panel, but I want it always to be shown.
After reviewing the other discussions about this issue, the best I could come up with was to add this to viewWillAppear:

```
self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = APP_DELEGATE.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
```

After doing that, the nav bar appears initially when the app launches but only if in portrait orientation.
As soon as the master panel is displayed, the nav bar disappears from the detail panel.
When the display is in landscape mode, the nav bar never displays.

I have also experimented with doing the same in the willChangeToDisplayMode delegate method, but the result is the same.

How can the nav bar be forced to stay on the detail view?